# Solving NAT problems on P2P

Tags: applet, p2p, nat

I am developing an applet for browser-to-browser application where User A knows User B's IP, requests connection through a port, and User B responds the request.

The main problem is that both users are behind a NAT, so just with the IP and the port is not possible to connect.

Which options do I have to solve this problem without forcing users to change their NAT configuration?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called TURN and STUN NAT traversal implementations. You may want to learn about [JXTA](http://jxse.kenai.com) or read the Practical JXTA II book online at Scribd for more information.